# Дизайн на разных Андроид версиях

Tags: android, xamarin

Начал использовать Xamarin в Visual Studio 2017 для создания приложений на Андроид. Первое приложение получилось, но ломается на разных версиях Андроид. К примеру, на 8ом Андроиде оно работает, а на 7ом ломается и некоторые элементы управления сваливаются в кучу.

Дизайн на 8ом:

[image: Дизайн на 8мом]

Дизайн на 7ом:

[image: Дизайн на 7мом]

Прошу помочь с адаптацией дизайна для 7ой версии Андроид

Comment: Хорошо, только уточните, в чем именно состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Как адаптировать дизайн под 7ю и 8ю версию, чтоб не ломалось

Comment: Добавьте уточнение в тело вопроса - кнопка "править"

Comment: Не видя разметки можно предположить что вы захардкодили размеры элементов

Comment: Прошу прощения, если туплю, но я не совсем понимаю, о какой видимой разметке идет речь. Xamarin начал изучать позавчера, много чего не знаю :D

Answer (score 0):

[Итак, проблема решена.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398652/same-design-on-different-android-versions)

Как я понял, дело было в том, что я вручную вводил позицию нижних элементов и они, на более маленьких экранах, не знали, куда деться и сжимались в кучу. Ответ одного человека помог мне разместить и зафиксировать эти элементы внизу так, что они уже никуда не денутся. Спасибо ему!